# Как спрятать js код? или запустить его удалённо?

Tags: javascript, шифрование

Суть: Есть web страница с полями для ввода информации, значений и т.д. и есть javascript код, который делает различные расчёты на основе введенных значений.

Вопрос: Есть ли возможность скрыть js код, чтобы его нельзя было скопировать? Либо, что лучше, возможность отправлять введенные значения в то место, где доступа к js коду у пользователя не будет, после там произвести вычисления и отправить результат обратно на сайт?

Какие есть вообще варианты?
Спасибо

Comment: что это за вычисления? секретные? тогда на сервер. просто вычислительные  - тогда и клиент сойдёт.

Comment: Просто какой смысл прятать JS код?

Comment: Просто js код используется в данном случае как язык программирования. Часть js для визуала останется на сайте, его да, смысла прятать нет. Можно подробней, как можно через сервер?

Comment: "Просто js код используется в данном случае как язык программирования" --- что значит эта фраза? любой язык программирования используется как язык программирования :D

Comment: "Можно подробней, как можно через сервер?" --- отсылается ajax запрос на сервер с исходными данными, на сервере происходит секретная логика и возвращается ответ. Клиент обрабатывает ответ.

Comment: Ага, уже есть хоть направление, в котором нужно идти) По фразе, да, я имел в виду, что там больше расчеты, которые с сайтом, с его визуалом не взаимодействуют, для чего собственно и js применяется в большей степени

Comment: Так на клиенте могут быть и расчёты (конечно зависит от степени тяжести и сложности). Js - не только для взаимодействия с UI, но и любые другие операции можно делать.

Comment: Понимаю, но смысл всех этих танцев, чтобы код нельзя было слизать со страницы. Скажем есть необходимость защитить, зашифровать интеллектуальную собственность) Может к решению этой задачи можно подключить node.js , информации мало, по этому пытаюсь разобраться

Comment: Понятно. Ну да, как я писал, если это "секретные" данные, логика, которые пользователь не должен видеть -  на сервер.... Node js да, можно, ведь он работает на сервере. В целом тут уже выбор серверного языка зависит от предпочтений разработчика, его знаний и умений в каком-то либо языке, решаемой задачи и т.д.

Comment: Короче, автор, без воды: надежно скрыть клиентский js-код невозможно, точка :) И шифрование тоже бесполезно, т.к. выполнение без расшифровки невозможно. А обфусцирование - совсем не защита, оно не спасет от тех кто действительно хочет стырить.

Comment: @yar85, а ненадежно как скрыть?

Comment: @Grundy ладошкой :D

Comment: На клиенте нельзя ничего скрыть. Вы сами отдаёте в браузер пользователя файлы с кодом и командой "слыш, запусти". Как бы что там не скрывалось, выход один — откроют и разберутся, а если не разберутся — скопипастят подчистую. Поэтому да, всё отправлять на сервер и отдавать только результат.

Comment: @Grundy, ненадежно можно всяко-разно... например, вшивать основной скрипт в изображение, размещая на странице сильно обфусцированный лоадер с "защитой" от отладчика (ну знаешь наверное, через спам `debugger;` по интервалу), который будет извлекать и инжектить/eval'ить спрятанный скрипт, а затем все подчищать.

Comment: @Grundy, еще можно организовать "легион ужаса" через сборку с разделением на множество взаимозависимых обфусцированных чанков с внедренным фальшивым кодом (>50%) в каждый. Время загрузки и производительность будут на уровне плинтуса, но зато будет довольно сложно реверсить какие-то вычисления в JS (если спрятать хочется именно их, а не работу с DOM и апишками). Подходит только для кода в функциональном стиле.